# $routeParams is undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I´m pretty noob in angular JS and I´m facing problem. the instruccion console.log($routeParams) show me a routeParams empty and I don´t know why.
I created my proyect using the ionic yeoman generator.

this is inside  my view (generates urls like this http://localhost:8100/#/app/tracking/50)

```
 <p ng-repeat="item in items">
   <a href="#/app/tracking/{{item .number}}" class="item item-icon-left">
     <i class="icon ion-home"></i>
      {{item .a}} - {{item .b}}
   </a>
 </p>
```

my router configuration in app.js

```
.state('app.tracking', {
    url: "/tracking/:idItem",
data: {
    requireLogin: true
  },
views: {
  'menuContent': {
    templateUrl: "templates/tracking.html",
    controller: 'TrackingCtrl'
  }
}
})
```

This is my controller (I tried to acces in those ways)

```
.controller('TrackingCtrl', function($scope,$routeParams) {

  console.log($routeParams);
  console.log($routeParams.idItem);
  console.log($routeParams["idItem"]);

})
```

I have ngRoute defined here int app.js

```
   angular.module('starter', ['ionic','angular-  md5','ngCordova','starter.controllers','ngRoute'])
```

And finally the reference to the bower component is the index

```
 <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
```

Thanks in advance for your time

Comment: use `$stateparams` instead of `$routeParams`

Comment: @K.Toress Thaks a lot that is the answer please post it to mark as valid,just  a minor thing is $stateParams. I Really apreciate your help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

seems like your using angular `ui-router` so you need to use `$stateParams` instead of `$routeParams`.